# Pick configuration of Serenity BDD from classpath

Tags: maven, configuration, classpath, serenity-bdd

I'm using Serenity BDD in development of my acceptance tests. I would like to keep several different configurations of the framework for executing tests in different environments (e.g. *local*, *docker*, etc). Also, I use Maven as build tool.

I know that's possible to arrange `.properties`-files into hierarchy right under project's root directory, like this:

```
myproject
   - serenity
        - local.properties
        - docker.properties
        ...
   - src
   - pom.xml
```

And then specify certain configuration via Maven command line:

```
mvn clean verify -Dproperties=serenity/local.properties
```

As said in [official documentation](http://thucydides.info/docs/serenity-staging/#_running_serenity_tests_from_the_command_line):

> properties
>
> Absolute path of the property file where Serenity system property defaults are defined. Defaults to ~/serenity.properties

But I wouldn't like to specify a path that's tied to file system. I would like to put those `.properties`-files into `src/test/resources/` and use a path that's tied to Java classpath.

I've tried:

```
mvn clean verify -Dproperties=classpath:serenity/local.properties
```

But that doesn't work.

Is it possible to pick `.properties`-file from classpath with Serenity BDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when running `mvn` the pom.xml is in the current working directory `pwd`
as far as I understand you are looking for a way to pass a relative path

try `mvn clean verify -Dproperties=$(pwd)/serenity/local.properties`